# Python Azure Durable Functions: how to change the local.settings.json file to read secrets off Azure Keyvault?

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-durable-functions

In Azure Durable Functions, this is what the `local.settings.json` file looks like for local debugging:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME>;AccountKey=<YOUR-ACCOUNT-KEY>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "ConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint=<XXXX>;AccountKey=<YYYY>;"
  }
}
```

How should the `ConnectionString` line be changed to make sure the Azure Durable Function reads the secrets from Azure Keyvault?

And is there anything else to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Key Vault references when debugging locally. That only works when deployed to Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

So the idea is that your local.settings.json might contain the actual secret connection string. But you will never check this file into your Git repo etc.